# Obtaining localhost URL of Python Kernel for Jupyter Notebook Interactive Window in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to find a way to manually retrieve local host URL of Python Kernel used by Jupyer Notebook Interactive Window running inside of VS Code (*Version: 1.71.0 (Universal) or higher*).

This URL used to show automatically when starting an interactive session in VS Code released in February 2022 (e.g.:, `Command + Shift + P > Jupyter: Create Interactive Window`). However, this is currently not shown in the recent versions of VS Code.

The following image (retrieved from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6484)) shows how the message looked like (VS Code February) and what do I mean by localhost URL:

[image]

I appreciate it is possible to downgrade VS Code. However, I would like to learn how trigger the message manually.

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6484) opened related to this which discusses the topic further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter `jupyter notebook` as command in the terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic command %connect_info

https://www.ds4n6.io/knowledge/tips_and_tricks/20100801.html